# An arithmetic problems

Tags: prime-numbers

"Find all the positive integers $n$ satisfying $2^n+n^2 +25 = p^3$ where $p$ is a prime number."
I proved that $n$ must be divisible by 6 and predicted $n=6, p=5$. However, I can't wrap it up. Thank you for all.

Comment: Not even seeing any other prime powers on that list, but I didn't search all that far.  I note that, with $n=24$, the left hand factors as $3079\times 348731$ which suggests that no simple congruence arguments will get you further.  Perhaps there is an algebraic factoring of the left hand?

Comment: The only non-negative integer $n\le 10^5$ , for which $2^n+n^2+25$ is a perfect power , if $n=6$

Comment: Found an answer on AoPS thanks to Approach0: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1068820h2165310p16080737

Comment: Wow thank you so much